# I have created z table with Plotly, now I want to highlights probability with red color for z=1.56 i.e 0.94062

Tags: python, plotly-python

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

def rejection_region():
    vals = [[0.50000, 0.53983, 0.57926, 0.61791, 0.65542, 0.69146, 0.72575, 0.75804, 0.78814, 0.81594, 0.84134, 0.86433, 0.88493, 0.90320, 0.91924, 0.93319, 0.94520, 0.95543, 0.96407, 0.97128, 0.97725, 0.98214, 0.98610, 0.98928, 0.99180, 0.99379, 0.99534, 0.99653, 0.99744, 0.99813, 0.99865, 0.99903, 0.99931, 0.99952, 0.99966, 0.99977, 0.99984, 0.99989, 0.99993, 0.99995
    ], [0.50399, 0.54380, 0.58317, 0.62172, 0.65910, 0.69497, 0.72907, 0.76115, 0.79103, 0.81859, 0.84375, 0.86650, 0.88686, 0.90490, 0.92073, 0.93448, 0.94630, 0.95637, 0.96485, 0.97193, 0.97778, 0.98257, 0.98645, 0.98956, 0.99202, 0.99396, 0.99547, 0.99664, 0.99752, 0.99819, 0.99869, 0.99906, 0.99934, 0.99953, 0.99968, 0.99978, 0.99985, 0.99990, 0.99993, 0.99995
    ], [0.50798, 0.54776, 0.58706, 0.62552, 0.66276, 0.69847, 0.73237, 0.76424, 0.79389, 0.82121, 0.84614, 0.86864, 0.88877, 0.90658, 0.92220, 0.93574, 0.94738, 0.95728, 0.96562, 0.97257, 0.97831, 0.98300, 0.98679, 0.98983, 0.99224, 0.99413, 0.99560, 0.99674, 0.99760, 0.99825, 0.99874, 0.99910, 0.99936, 0.99955, 0.99969, 0.99978, 0.99985, 0.99990, 0.99993, 0.99996
    ],[0.51197, 0.55172, 0.59095, 0.62930, 0.66640, 0.70194, 0.73565, 0.76730, 0.79673, 0.82381, 0.84849, 0.87076, 0.89065, 0.90824, 0.92364, 0.93699, 0.94845, 0.95818, 0.96638, 0.97320, 0.97882, 0.98341, 0.98713, 0.99010, 0.99245, 0.99430, 0.99573, 0.99683, 0.99767, 0.99831, 0.99878, 0.99913, 0.99938, 0.99957, 0.99970, 0.99979, 0.99986, 0.99990, 0.99994, 0.99996
    ],[0.51595, 0.55567, 0.59483, 0.63307, 0.67003, 0.70540, 0.73891, 0.77035, 0.79955, 0.82639, 0.85083, 0.87286, 0.89251, 0.90988, 0.92507, 0.93822, 0.94950, 0.95907, 0.96712, 0.97381, 0.97932, 0.98382, 0.98745, 0.99036, 0.99266, 0.99446, 0.99585, 0.99693, 0.99774, 0.99836, 0.99882, 0.99916, 0.99940, 0.99958, 0.99971, 0.99980, 0.99986, 0.99991, 0.99994, 0.99996
    ],[0.51994, 0.55962, 0.59871, 0.63683, 0.67364, 0.70884, 0.74215, 0.77337, 0.80234, 0.82894, 0.85314, 0.87493, 0.89435, 0.91149, 0.92647, 0.93943, 0.95053, 0.95994, 0.96784, 0.97441, 0.97982, 0.98422, 0.98778, 0.99061, 0.99286, 0.99461, 0.99598, 0.99702, 0.99781, 0.99841, 0.99886, 0.99918, 0.99942, 0.99960, 0.99972, 0.99981, 0.99987, 0.99991, 0.99994, 0.99996
    ],[0.52392, 0.56356, 0.60257, 0.64058, 0.67724, 0.71226, 0.74537, 0.77637, 0.80511, 0.83147, 0.85543, 0.87698, 0.89617, 0.91309, 0.92785, 0.94062, 0.95154, 0.96080, 0.96856, 0.97500, 0.98030, 0.98461, 0.98809, 0.99086, 0.99305, 0.99477, 0.99609, 0.99711, 0.99788, 0.99846, 0.99889, 0.99921, 0.99944, 0.99961, 0.99973, 0.99981, 0.99987, 0.99992, 0.99994, 0.99996
    ],[0.52790, 0.56749, 0.60642, 0.64431, 0.68082, 0.71566, 0.74857, 0.77935, 0.80785, 0.83398, 0.85769, 0.87900, 0.89796, 0.91466, 0.92922, 0.94179, 0.95254, 0.96164, 0.96926, 0.97558, 0.98077, 0.98500, 0.98840, 0.99111, 0.99324, 0.99492, 0.99621, 0.99720, 0.99795, 0.99851, 0.99893, 0.99924, 0.99946, 0.99962, 0.99974, 0.99982, 0.99988, 0.99992, 0.99995, 0.99996
    ],[0.53188, 0.57142, 0.61026, 0.64803, 0.68439, 0.71904, 0.75175, 0.78230, 0.81057, 0.83646, 0.85993, 0.88100, 0.89973, 0.91621, 0.93056, 0.94295, 0.95352, 0.96246, 0.96995, 0.97615, 0.98124, 0.98537, 0.98870, 0.99134, 0.99343, 0.99506, 0.99632, 0.99728, 0.99801, 0.99856, 0.99896, 0.99926, 0.99948, 0.99964, 0.99975, 0.99983, 0.99988, 0.99992, 0.99995, 0.99997
    ],[0.53586, 0.57535, 0.61409, 0.65173, 0.68793, 0.72240, 0.75490, 0.78524, 0.81327, 0.83891, 0.86214, 0.88298, 0.90147, 0.91774, 0.93189, 0.94408, 0.95449, 0.96327, 0.97062, 0.97670, 0.98169, 0.98574, 0.98899, 0.99158, 0.99361, 0.99520, 0.99643, 0.99736, 0.99807, 0.99861, 0.99900, 0.99929, 0.99950, 0.99965, 0.99976, 0.99983, 0.99989, 0.99992, 0.99995, 0.99997
    
    ]]

    z = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0,
         2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9
         ]
    font_color = ['rgb(40,40,40)'] 

    table_trace = go.Table(
        columnwidth=[100] + [100] + [100]+ [100]+[100] + [100] + [100]+ [100]+[100]+ [100]+ [100] ,

        columnorder=[0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
        header=dict(height=10,
                    values=[['<b>z</b>'], ['<b>0.00</b>'], ['<b>0.01</b>'], ['<b>0.02</b>'], ['<b>0.03</b>'], ['<b>0.04</b>'], ['<b>0.05</b>'], ['<b>0.06</b>'], ['<b>0.07</b>'], ['<b>0.08</b>'], ['<b>0.09</b>']],

                    line=dict(color='rgb(50,50,50)'),
                    align=['left'] * 3,
                    font=dict(color=['rgb(45,45,45)'] * 3, size=14),


                    ),
        cells=dict(values=[z , vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5], vals[6], vals[7], vals[8], vals[9]],
                   line=dict(color='#506784'),
                   align=['left'] * 5,

                   font=dict(family="Arial", size=14, color=font_color),
                   format=[None, ",.5f"],

                   height=20,
                   fill=dict(color='rgb(245,245,245)'))

    )

    layout = go.Layout(width=900, height=1100, autosize=False,
                       title_text='p-value from z table',
                       title_x=0.5, showlegend=False)
    fig = go.Figure(data=[table_trace], layout=layout)


    st.plotly_chart(fig)








if (st.button("calculate")):
    rejection_region()
```

## Output table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTbVq.png)

Comment: The code formatting in this question was rather broken. I have tried to repair it, but please check.